# Date range to string for humans

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I have a calendar system so an event have a `start` and an `end` date. Like any calendar the `end` date is optionnal and can also can be the same as the `start` date but with different time.

So there are multiple combinations to display it for humans (like in Google Calendar or Apple Calendar, etc) depending on the dates :

- 1 jan 2019
- 1 jan 2019 at 08:12
- 1 jan 2019 at 08:12 to 11:45
- 1 jan 2019 to the 3 feb 2019
- 1 jan 2019 at 10:15 to the 3 feb 2019 18:20
- etc

Is there a built-in way in Php-Carbon to do this ? I only find methods to format one date, but not en interval/period. Thanks

Comment: Why not simply `$start->format(...) . ' to the ' . $end->format(...)`?

Comment: Because you can have a start and end date that are the same with just different hours and you would have `1 jan 2019 at 08:12 to 11:45`. Right now I do it with a custom method that does all this checks but was wondering if there was a built-in way that I missed

Comment: Fair enough, but I haven't seen any such thing in the docs. I tend to write a wrapper like you did. It's probably the only good way at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you can do something like this:

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create($start, $end);
```

Then you can iterate over the period and do whatever you wish with it.

This was added in Carbon 1.29

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following code...

```
printf("Right now is %s", Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
printf("Right now in Vancouver is %s", Carbon::now('America/Vancouver')); // automatically converted to string
$tomorrow = Carbon::now()->addDay();
$lastWeek = Carbon::now()->subWeek();

// Carbon embed 824 languages:
echo $tomorrow->locale('fr')->isoFormat('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');
echo $tomorrow->locale('ar')->isoFormat('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');

$officialDate = Carbon::now()->toRfc2822String();

$howOldAmI = Carbon::createFromDate(1975, 5, 21)->age;

$noonTodayLondonTime = Carbon::createFromTime(12, 0, 0, 'Europe/London');

$internetWillBlowUpOn = Carbon::create(2038, 01, 19, 3, 14, 7, 'GMT');

if (Carbon::now()->isWeekend()) {
    echo 'Party!';
}
echo Carbon::now()->subMinutes(2)->diffForHumans(); // '2 minutes ago'
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question so that simply the difference should be formatted:

```
$start = new Carbon('1 jan 2019 08:12');
$end = new Carbon('today');

echo $start->diffForHumans($end);
//10 months before
```